# Building all permutations of a certain String and check it against a dictionary efficiently

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, dictionary, permutation

I have a certain String (from a Radio talkshow), which is an anagram with a length of 15.

What I want to do is to build all permutations efficiently and check them against a dictionary.

This way I want to find out the original word of the anagram.

I already wrote an alogithm, which is working by always merging one letter after the other in the already known permutations.

It is working, but it is too slow. There is never any result shown with 15 chracters (no wonder with 15! possibilities).

So my question is, how to do that faster?

Comment: Why do you want to build all the permutations if the  String is already given?

Comment: This could be a very interesting problem, but perhaps you can provide more information. Do the 15 characters include spaces and other duplicate characters? Does the dictionary contains words or phrases? If words, can you be certain that it contains all of the words in the string? Taking the answers to these questions into consideration you might find that there are far fewer possibilities. A branch and algorithm could be used to limit the number of trials to test.

Answer (score 0):

for every word in your dictionary/array/set - sort letters in this word and store in separate dictionary/map, something like (in pseudo code)

```
Set<String> originalDictionary = {"word", "string"};
Map<String, String> sortedMap = {
"dorw" => "word", "ginrst" => "string"}
};
```

for your input string - sort letter again and check whether you have something in your dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how large your dictionary is, but assume it has much less than 15! entries. So I would go through all dictionary entries and find the ones with length 15. Checking if they are permutations of your original string should be easy.